# filter GET request with params

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I want to filter Todo.find by username from axios.get request.The problem is it is not returning anything
Any suggestions?

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios
        .get("http://localhost:8080/${username}",{
            // username : this.state.username
        })
        .then((res) => {
            this.setState({todos: res.data})
            console.log('--------res.data', res.data);
            this.setPageCount()
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("err", err);
        });
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
console.log('Welcome to roffys server')
Todo.find({username:req.params.username})
    .exec((err, todo) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error retrieving todos')
        } else {
            console.log(req.body.username)
            res.json(todo)
        }
    })
})
```

Also I want to send params from other component and I dont know how

This is the function which changes Username,It is in another component:

```
 handleLogIn = () => {
        const { username, password } = this.state
        if (password.length === 0 || username.length === 0 ) {
            alert('Incorrect Login!')
        } else {
            axios
                .post(`http://localhost:8080/logIn`, {
                    username: username,
                    password: password,
                })
                .then((res) => {
                    this.setState({username: username,password: password})
                    localStorage.setItem('username',this.state.username)
                    this.props.history.push("/todoapp");
                    window.location.reload(false)
                    console.log(this.state.username)
                    console.log('res',res)
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log("err", err);
                });
        }
    }
```

BackEnd Side :

```
app.get('/:username', (req, res) => {
console.log('Welcome to roffys server')
Todo.find({'username': req.params.username})
    .exec((err, todo) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error retrieving todos')
        } else {
            res.json(todo)
        }
    })

})
```

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a way you can transfer the username.

Answer (score 0):

You're incorrectly using the template literal, should be as follows:

```
.get(`http://localhost:8080/${username}`)
```

and shouldn't you accept a dynamic param? like this:

`app.get('/:username', (req, res) => { // ...`

**Update:**

Regarding transferring the username to the other component, you can do this:

```
this.props.history.push({
  pathname: '/todoapp',
  state: { username: this.state.username }
})
```

and in the todo component:

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios
        .get(`http://localhost:8080/${this.props.location.state.username}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

should be:

```
`http://localhost:8080/${username}`
```

not `"http://localhost:8080/${username}"`